# How to make PYGAME window appear on left corner of my monitor?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a visualization in PYGAME, but the window appears on some random position of my monitor and sometimes some part of the window is obstructed by my taskbar.

[image]

Above is a screenshot of where the window appeared. As you can see the bottom of the window is obstructed by my taskbar.

How can I have the pygame window appear on the top left of my monitor? I checked the pygame documentation, but couldn't find any answers.

Below is how I have set up my pygame window.

```
# pygame config
pygame.init()
WIN_WIDTH = 700
WIN_HEIGHT = 700
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("A* Pathfinding Algorithm")
window.fill(colors['white'])
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the position of the pygame window by:

```py
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(100, 100)
```

You have to set the position before initializing the window by [`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)